# Visual Studio indicates error RZ1024 on javascript code inside <text> block

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

Recently I've updated Visual Studio 2019 to the latest version (16.3.8), and changed net core SDK to 3.0.

My project is an asp net core based project. In my index.cshtml file, visual studio is showing an error code RZ1024:

*End of file or an unexpected character was reached before the "" tag could be parsed [...]*

The code is the same that works with the later Visual Studio and net core 2.2:

[image]

Specifically, the error is the '<' character of the 'for' block. I think VS is detecting this char like an opening html tag.

[image]

I've googled searching some info about error code RZ1024, with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Use `@Html.Raw()` to display a less than sign as below :

```
for (i = 0; i @Html.Raw("<") records.length; i++)
{ // ...}
```

Comment: It works. it's strange that the original code worked before and now it doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

To "cheat" Razor preserving the possibility to use intellisense for Javascript validation, just add a comment at the end of the line with the opposite parenthesis:

```
if (a<1) {                    //>
```